# 3r Party AuthProvider - callback url redirect

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic3, oauth-provider, callbackurl

My project includes the firebase sign-in methods: Twitter, Facebook, Google and Github. 
I am using  **firebase.auth().signInWithPopup()** to handle authentication and callback. It works fine when run in the browser:

in mobile, this is different. I realize that it opens a new safari window, but it does not redirect to the app home screen. How can we do that?

[image]

this is the project in the firebase console for the Facebook sign-in
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue for home screen apps in iOS. The window that is opened is sandboxed from the home screen app. The popup is unable to pass back the result to the parent home screen app. Instead, you should use `signInWithRedirect` in that mode. I believe that should work.